# Propel ORM Concurrent Connections

Tags: php, mysql, database, concurrency, propel

I am working on a project using Propel ORM and need to connect to two different databases to retrieve certain data.  I've attempted searching online for a guide, but had no luck as all the "solutions" were either specific to Symphony or just simply did not work.

I would like to be able to have two connections specified and be able to switch between them during certain queries by passing a connection alias to the query.  However, it is also acceptable to have both connections open simultaneously.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Dima

Comment: is absolutely necessary to use 2 databases? more than 1 databes normaly is the result of a bad design. If it's necessary, think about web services from one of the databases

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Propel API Docs](http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html#database_connection_name) you can define a database connection in your schema.xml file in such a manner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="bookstore" defaultIdMethod="native">
    <!-- table definitions go here -->
</database>
```

Then in your [runtime-conf.xml](http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html#runtime_connection_settings) settings you can set the connection params:

```
<datasources default="bookstore">
  <datasource id="bookstore">
    <adapter>mysql</adapter> <!-- sqlite, mysql, mssql, oracle, or pgsql -->
    <connection>
      <dsn>mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name</dsn>
      <user>my_db_user</user>
      <password>my_db_password</password>
    </connection>
  </datasource>
</datasources>
```

-- Edit --

Doesn't appear that Propel supports an alias attribute for the database tag, but you should be able to get away with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="bookstore_primary" defaultIdMethod="native">
    <!-- table definitions go here -->
</database>

<database name="bookstore_secondary" defaultIdMethod="native">
    <!-- table definitions go here -->
</database>

<datasources default="bookstore_primary">
  <datasource id="bookstore_primary">
    <adapter>mysql</adapter> <!-- sqlite, mysql, mssql, oracle, or pgsql -->
    <connection>
      <dsn>mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bookstore_primary</dsn>
      <user>my_db_user</user>
      <password>my_db_password</password>
    </connection>
  </datasource>
</datasources>

<datasources default="bookstore_secondary">
  <datasource id="bookstore_secondary">
    <adapter>mysql</adapter> <!-- sqlite, mysql, mssql, oracle, or pgsql -->
    <connection>
      <dsn>mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bookstore_secondary</dsn>
      <user>my_db_user</user>
      <password>my_db_password</password>
    </connection>
  </datasource>
</datasources>
```

See if that works. At the end of the day the thing that really matters is that a connection can be made to both databases (using respective DSNs).

Comment: Thanks for you answer Mike!  The problem that I encountered with this approach is that in the runtime-conf.xml, the datasource element's ID must match the name of the database in the schema.  For my project, both databases have the same names, so if I add them both into my runtime-conf, they'll have the same alias... :\

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  My team and I ended up finding some other work-arounds for the desired functionality we wanted.  We're approaching our deadline and need the functionality regardless of implementation.  I'm sure we'll come back to this issue after our beta launch.